# How to add a line break

Tags: jquery, html, line-breaks

I'm not good at jQuery at all so please someone help me.
I need to add a line break between the name and the email address.

Right now, the output is:

> Messages hello@hello.net.

I need it to be:

> Messages
> hello@hello.net

Here's the code

```
var tabs = [
new Tab({
    name: "tab1",
    text: "Messages hello@hello.net"
})
]
```

Comment: \r\n or \r or \n try them like "Messages \n hello@hello.net"

Answer (score 0):

Use \n to create a new line

```
var tabs = [
new Tab({
    name: "tab1",
    text: "Messages\nhello@hello.net"
})]
```

Comment: @user3079066 What are you trying to do with the string, append it to an element or alert it or log it in the console?

Comment: I'm trying to append it.

Comment: @user3079066 Try using <br> instead of \n then

Answer (score 0):

Is the 'text' going to be displayed in HTML?

Maybe adding a br-tag would do the trick for you.

```
var tabs = [
new Tab({
    name: "tab1",
    text: "Messages<br/>hello@hello.net"
})]
```

A nicer way might be splitting the text in separate parts, this way its more flexibel for styling etc.:

```
var tabs = [
new Tab({
    name: "tab1",
    prefix: "Messages",
    text: "hello@hello.net"
})]
```

This is only possible if you have control over whats going on in 'Tab'.